# levelplot box line width R

Tags: r, width, lattice, box, levelplot

Does any know how to change the line width of a `levelplot` graphic, especially that with multiple panels? The box line width should change alongside the tick marks. In base `R` one can use `plot(x);box(lwd=10)`.

Is this possible within levelplot?

Many thanks.

```
library(rasterVis)
mycolors=c("darkred","red3", "orange", "yellow", "lightskyblue", 
          "royalblue3","darkblue")
s <- stack(replicate(6, raster(matrix(runif(100), 10))))
levelplot(s, layout=c(3, 2), col.regions=mycolors, index.cond=list(c(1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 6)))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the border line widths with the `par.settings` argument. For example:

```
levelplot(s, layout=c(3, 2), col.regions=mycolors, 
          index.cond=list(c(1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 6)), 
          par.settings=list(axis.line=list(lwd=3), strip.border=list(lwd=3)))
```

[image]

Comment: Great answer! This makes my plot look better after exporting in high resolution using the Cairo package.

Comment: You will get a better color key if you define a new theme with `rasterTheme` instead of using `col.regions`. Thus, `myTheme <- rasterTheme(region = mycolors)` and `myTheme <- modifyList(myTheme, list(axis.line=list(lwd=3),                           strip.border=list(lwd=3)))`. Finally, assign this `myTheme` list to `par.settings`.